# Is it possible to make android discrete seekbar show progress without clicking on it?

Tags: android, slider, seekbar

I am using the material design for my discrete bar. More specific this ones
`Discrete bars`. So what I need is to be able to see the progress without clicking on it. Soo far from my researches I found nothing for this. Something like this in `first` and `second` activity.

**Discrete Bars**

[image: Discrete bars]

**First Activity**

[image: First]

**Second Activity**

[image: Second]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774963/android-seekbar-show-progress-value-along-the-seekbar

Comment: Maybe useful: https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar, https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar

Comment: It is the same problem with this repositories. I get the progress only by clicking on the seekbar.