# make center text view of thumb and move text view with Seek bar progress

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-tv

For AndroidTV I have created a simple seek bar and text view. I am trying to align text view of seek bar thumb and trying to move with progress.

Tried these solutions but it's not working [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774963/android-seekbar-show-progress-value-along-the-seekbar), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722746/add-dynamic-text-over-android-seekbar-thumb)

Sample Code
logic to get x position of text view

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            int width = seekBar.getWidth()
                        - seekBar.getPaddingLeft()
                        - seekBar.getPaddingRight();
            float thumbPos = width
                             * seekBar.getProgress()
                             / seekBar.getMax();
            textView.setX(width );
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffff00"/>

  <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/previewSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:min="1"
        android:max="10"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected

1. Textview should move with seek bar progress.
2. Textview should be in the center of thumb and above seek bar like in screenshot.
3. Text view should move when progress > text view width/2 && progress

Comment: logic used to get x position
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
{ 
@Override public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser) 
{ 
if (fromUser)
 { 
int width = seekBar.getWidth() - seekBar.getPaddingLeft() - seekBar.getPaddingRight();
 float thumbPos =width * seekBar.getProgress() / seekBar.getMax(); textView.setX(width ); 
} }

Comment: Kindly format your code "the logic that you explained". Its very hard to understand your logic. 

You just need to set correct X/Y values to the text view or you can translate them. The base logic is to calculate correct values of X and Y

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for late answer, your logic is correct but it requires few changes.

```
float thumbPos = width * (seekBar.getProgress() / (float)seekBar.getMax())

textView.setTranslationX(thumbPos) ;
```

`seekBar.getProgress()` is an `int` and `seekBar.getMax()` is also an `int`, if divide them they will return **integer value**, but we need **float**(in decimal) that's why I have added the changes

Comment: Rahul thanks for reply but it's not working even after change int to float.can you please give some sample?

Comment: Hi Kalpana I have uploaded a sample project, kindly run the app & check the code in MainActivity.kt url - https://github.com/iamdangerous/TranslateTextWithSeekbar